# Uploaded file in fileparameter not found after some time waiting in Jenkins queue

Tags: jenkins, hudson

We use a free-style job in Jenkins with a file parameter to launch a job that reads that file to perform some actions.
Sometimes we want to schedule this job (with the help of the [Schedule Build plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/schedule-build/)) with a file to be launched during the week-end (typically on Sunday). The job in this case can stay up to two days in the waiting queue and when it is launched after waiting we have this error:

```
FATAL: Cannot invoke "org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem.getName()" because "this.this$0.file" is null
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem.getName()" because "this.this$0.file" is null
    at hudson.model.FileParameterValue$1.setUp(FileParameterValue.java:160)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:158)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:526)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1900)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:44)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:101)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:442)
```

We use a Jenkins instance in a Docker container in version 2.387.2.

I did try to search if there is a Jenkins options (in the UI or in the command line) relative to temporary file retention duration but I did not find anything that seems to control this behavior.

Other searches on Google or here on SO didn't gave me any pointers to what to do to avoid this error.